# function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is invalid in C99

Tags: c, header, swig

I am trying to run "make" inside a tool directory and I am getting the error I mentioned in the title a number of times. I know how to get rid of similar errors by including C headers. However, I don't know for exactly this function where to find a header. An internet search also didn't help much.

I am using Mac OS Big Sur with a `gcc -v` as

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Any idea where to find such a header to get rid of this error?

```
$ make
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/lib
rm -f *.so *.o *_wrap.c
gfortran -O2 -fPIC -g -c ../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f -o particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.o
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:458:72:

  458 |          DO 213 N1=1,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 213 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:489:72:

  489 |             DO 214 N1=1,NM
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 214 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:803:72:

  803 |          DO 5 N=1,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 5 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:827:72:

  827 |             DO 400 N=NMIN,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 400 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:984:72:

  984 |            DO 10 N1=1,N
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 10 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1204:72:

 1204 |            DO 10 N=1,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 10 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1259:72:

 1259 |     5     Y(I+1)=DFLOAT(2*I+1)*X1*Y(I)-Y(I-1)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 5 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1262:72:

 1262 |   10       V(I)=Y(I-1)-DFLOAT(I)*X1*Y(I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 10 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1401:72:

 1401 |          DO 25 N=1,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 25 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1416:72:

 1416 |            DO 300 N2=MM1,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 300 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1511:72:

 1511 |            DO 310 N2=MM1,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 310 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1548:72:

 1548 |            DO 320 N2=1,NNMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 320 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1616:72:

 1616 |          DO 25 N=1,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 25 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1634:72:

 1634 |            DO 300 N2=MM1,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 300 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1779:72:

 1779 |            DO 310 N2=MM1,NMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 310 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:1826:72:

 1826 |            DO 320 N2=1,NNMAX
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 320 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:2092:72:

 2092 |    20         PC=X*PB+(X*PB-PA)*(DJ-A)/DJ
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 20 at (1)
../src/particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.f:2119:72:

 2119 |   120     Z(I)=(A+Z(I))/B
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 120 at (1)
gfortran -O2 -fPIC -g -c ../src/particles_mishchenko2000_lpd.f -o particles_mishchenko2000_lpd.o
swig -python -outcurrentdir ../src/wrapwindfield.i
gcc -o _wrapwindfield.so wrapwindfield_wrap.c ../src/coordinates.c ../src/edr.c ../src/fields.c ../src/func.c ../src/interpolation.c ../src/ltqnorm.c ../src/particles.c ../src/particles_mishchenko2000.c ../src/radarfilter.c ../src/retrieval_fdvar.c ../src/retrieval_lwm.c ../src/specialfunctions.c ../src/util.c ../src/util_turbulence.c ../src/wrapradarfilter.c ../src/wrapretrieval.c ../src/wrapwindfield.c ../src/zephyros_config.c particles_mishchenko2000_ampld.lp.o particles_mishchenko2000_lpd.o -I../src/ -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/suitesparse/ -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -lcxsparse -lnlopt -O2 -lgfortran -lm -shared -fPIC
wrapwindfield_wrap.c:1756:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      0,                                    /* tp_print */
      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 
      'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: 
      expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
#define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                     ^
wrapwindfield_wrap.c:1923:7: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      0,                                    /* tp_print */
      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 
      'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: 
      expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
#define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                     ^
wrapwindfield_wrap.c:2729:2: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        }
        ^
wrapwindfield_wrap.c:4127:9: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        0,                                  /* tp_print */
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/cpython/object.h:260:5: note: 
      'tp_print' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    Py_DEPRECATED(3.8) int (*tp_print)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pyport.h:515:54: note: 
      expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
#define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                     ^
4 warnings generated.
../src/fields.c:146:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is invalid in
      C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        func_dbl_arr_calloc(field->n_x, &field->vec_x);
        ^
../src/fields.c:227:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths
      [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
../src/fields.c:233:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
../src/fields.c:237:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
../src/fields.c:241:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
../src/fields.c:245:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
5 warnings and 1 error generated.
../src/func.c:905:7: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of
      floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
                i = abs(x / y);
                    ^
../src/func.c:905:7: note: use function 'fabs' instead
                i = abs(x / y);
                    ^~~
                    fabs
1 warning generated.
../src/interpolation.c:860:7: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is
      of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
                i = abs(x / y);
                    ^
../src/interpolation.c:860:7: note: use function 'fabs' instead
                i = abs(x / y);
                    ^~~
                    fabs
1 warning generated.
../src/radarfilter.c:199:44: warning: for loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
                        for (i = 0;  i < 35;  i++, printf("\b")); printf("calculate measurem...
                                                                ^
../src/radarfilter.c:199:44: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
../src/radarfilter.c:322:45: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is
      invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                if (rcfg->filter_Doppler_spectrum_dBZ_hh) func_dbl_arr_calloc(radarmeasureme...
                                                          ^
../src/radarfilter.c:322:45: note: did you mean 'func_dbl_arr_malloc'?
../src/func.h:136:6: note: 'func_dbl_arr_malloc' declared here
void func_dbl_arr_malloc(
     ^
../src/radarfilter.c:1571:3: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
                /*
                ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
../src/retrieval_fdvar.c:149:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is
      invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        func_dbl_arr_calloc(p->Kn, &xu);
        ^
../src/retrieval_fdvar.c:149:2: note: did you mean 'func_dbl_arr_malloc'?
../src/func.h:136:6: note: 'func_dbl_arr_malloc' declared here
void func_dbl_arr_malloc(
     ^
../src/retrieval_fdvar.c:214:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
../src/retrieval_fdvar.c:1233:65: warning: invalid conversion specifier ')'
      [-Wformat-invalid-specifier]
        if (calc_costfunction) {printf("current cost value: %.5e (%.2e%)\n"   , *f, 100.*(*...
                                                                      ~^
../src/retrieval_fdvar.c:1286:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is
      invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        func_dbl_arr_calloc(p->Kn, x);
        ^
../src/retrieval_fdvar.c:1891:39: warning: comparison of array
      'zc->retrieval->post_windfield->lut_u' not equal to a null pointer is always true
      [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
                        if (zc->retrieval->post_windfield->lut_u != NULL)
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~    ~~~~
../src/retrieval_fdvar.c:1897:39: warning: comparison of array
      'zc->retrieval->post_windfield->lut_v' not equal to a null pointer is always true
      [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
                        if (zc->retrieval->post_windfield->lut_v != NULL)
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~    ~~~~
../src/retrieval_fdvar.c:1903:39: warning: comparison of array
      'zc->retrieval->post_windfield->lut_w' not equal to a null pointer is always true
      [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
                        if (zc->retrieval->post_windfield->lut_w != NULL)
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~    ~~~~
../src/retrieval_fdvar.c:2217:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is
      invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        func_dbl_arr_calloc( p->Kn, &p->Klbound);
        ^
5 warnings and 3 errors generated.
../src/retrieval_lwm.c:114:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is
      invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        func_dbl_arr_calloc(p->Kn, &K);
        ^
../src/retrieval_lwm.c:182:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
../src/retrieval_lwm.c:494:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'randompermutation' is invalid
      in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                randompermutation(n_ep, &my_permutation);
                ^
../src/retrieval_lwm.c:759:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is
      invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        func_dbl_arr_calloc(o->n, &o->windvector_u );   
        ^
../src/retrieval_lwm.c:767:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_int_arr_malloc' is
      invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        func_int_arr_malloc(o->n, &o->used_for_analysis);       
        ^
../src/retrieval_lwm.c:767:2: note: did you mean 'func_dbl_arr_calloc'?
../src/retrieval_lwm.c:114:2: note: 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' declared here
        func_dbl_arr_calloc(p->Kn, &K);
        ^
../src/retrieval_lwm.c:830:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is
      invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        func_dbl_arr_calloc(p->field->n, &p->u0 );      
        ^
1 warning and 5 errors generated.
../src/util.c:1236:42: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses
      [-Wparentheses]
                        if (thepsd->grid_number_density_m3[i] = NULL);
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
../src/util.c:1236:42: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
                        if (thepsd->grid_number_density_m3[i] = NULL);
                                                              ^
                            (                                       )
../src/util.c:1236:42: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
                        if (thepsd->grid_number_density_m3[i] = NULL);
                                                              ^
                                                              ==
../src/util.c:1236:49: warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]
                        if (thepsd->grid_number_density_m3[i] = NULL);
                                                                     ^
../src/util.c:1236:49: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
../src/util.c:1326:48: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses
      [-Wparentheses]
                        if (thepsd->grid_dBnumber_density_err_m3[i] = NULL);
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
../src/util.c:1326:48: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
                        if (thepsd->grid_dBnumber_density_err_m3[i] = NULL);
                                                                    ^
                            (                                             )
../src/util.c:1326:48: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
                        if (thepsd->grid_dBnumber_density_err_m3[i] = NULL);
                                                                    ^
                                                                    ==
../src/util.c:1326:55: warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]
                        if (thepsd->grid_dBnumber_density_err_m3[i] = NULL);
                                                                           ^
../src/util.c:1326:55: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
../src/util.c:1635:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'func_dbl_arr_calloc' is invalid in
      C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                func_dbl_arr_calloc(n, &dst);
                ^
../src/util.c:1635:3: note: did you mean 'func_dbl_arr_malloc'?
../src/func.h:136:6: note: 'func_dbl_arr_malloc' declared here
void func_dbl_arr_malloc(
     ^
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
../src/util_turbulence.c:1020:16: warning: & has lower precedence than <; < will be evaluated first
      [-Wparentheses]
  ...if ((i == 0) & (((cfg->Lx / cfg->Nx) * fct)) < (cfg->minL_div_maxL * cfg->Lx)) break;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/util_turbulence.c:1020:16: note: place parentheses around the '<' expression to silence this
      warning
  ...if ((i == 0) & (((cfg->Lx / cfg->Nx) * fct)) < (cfg->minL_div_maxL * cfg->Lx)) break;
                  ^
                    (                                                             )
../src/util_turbulence.c:1020:16: note: place parentheses around the & expression to evaluate it
      first
                if ((i == 0) & (((cfg->Lx / cfg->Nx) * fct)) < (cfg->minL_div_maxL * cfg->Lx...
                             ^
                    (                                       )
../src/util_turbulence.c:1021:16: warning: & has lower precedence than <; < will be evaluated first
      [-Wparentheses]
  ...if ((i == 1) & (((cfg->Ly / cfg->Ny) * fct)) < (cfg->minL_div_maxL * cfg->Ly)) break;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/util_turbulence.c:1021:16: note: place parentheses around the '<' expression to silence this
      warning
  ...if ((i == 1) & (((cfg->Ly / cfg->Ny) * fct)) < (cfg->minL_div_maxL * cfg->Ly)) break;
                  ^
                    (                                                             )
../src/util_turbulence.c:1021:16: note: place parentheses around the & expression to evaluate it
      first
                if ((i == 1) & (((cfg->Ly / cfg->Ny) * fct)) < (cfg->minL_div_maxL * cfg->Ly...
                             ^
                    (                                       )
../src/util_turbulence.c:1022:16: warning: & has lower precedence than <; < will be evaluated first
      [-Wparentheses]
  ...if ((i == 2) & (((cfg->Lz / cfg->Nz) * fct)) < (cfg->minL_div_maxL * cfg->Lz)) break;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/util_turbulence.c:1022:16: note: place parentheses around the '<' expression to silence this
      warning
  ...if ((i == 2) & (((cfg->Lz / cfg->Nz) * fct)) < (cfg->minL_div_maxL * cfg->Lz)) break;
                  ^
                    (                                                             )
../src/util_turbulence.c:1022:16: note: place parentheses around the & expression to evaluate it
      first
                if ((i == 2) & (((cfg->Lz / cfg->Nz) * fct)) < (cfg->minL_div_maxL * cfg->Lz...
                             ^
                    (                                       )
../src/util_turbulence.c:1215:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control
      paths [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
4 warnings generated.
make: *** [wrapwindfield] Error 1
```

I am also doubtful about the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I use for one of the configurations in the `linux_compliation_settings.mk` file. I use it as `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib` . Should it be something else for MacOS?

I am attaching the link to my Github repository where I have this tool. If you go into the `wrapwindfield` directory, you can find the makefile with which I want to `make` the tool.

I am using python 3.8 and the path to my python and numpy headers are given in `linux_compliation_settings.mk`.

Link to git: https://github.com/tworitdash/zephyros0.4

Comment: Add the declaration to "src/func.h". See "src/func.c" for the function definition.

Comment: I found 'func_dbl_arr_malloc' instead of 'func_dbl_arr_calloc'. Anyway, I just changed the name and it works. Thanks :)